# Why is the "lounge-mobile.css" stylesheet not linking when I reduce my browser size?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

If i change my browser size to less than 500px the mobile-lounge.css should link (to test I changed body-background to black in mobile-lounge).

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Head First Lounge</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="lounge.css" media="screen and (min-width: 500px)">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="lounge-mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 499px)">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="lounge-print.css" media="print">
  </head>
```

Comment: Have tried changing window size and reloading the page?

Comment: Try to set this meta tag in the `<head>`: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and check if it works

Comment: @JohanB — The OP said they were resizing their browser window, that implies they are using a desktop browser so meta viewport will have no effect.

Comment: Using @media is working but using it in <link> is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think following code will help you CSS link will help,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 201px) and (max-width: 500px)' href="lounge-mobile.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this once, this might help

```html
media="(max-width: 499px)"
```